# Mysql - No Addition in my Calc Query

Tags: mysql

I will make an calculation of notes and i realise that with an MySQL Query.
Here the whole Query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Round(Avg(avg = 2) * Count(avg)) AS New,
                sma_famille.famille
FROM   (SELECT DISTINCT Round(Sum(note) / Count(note)) AS AVG,
                        sma_famille.famille,
                        sma_agents.nom
        FROM   sma_notes_conso
               INNER JOIN sma_famille
                       ON sma_famille.id_service
               INNER JOIN sma_agents
                       ON sma_notes_conso.id_agent = sma_agents.id_agent
               INNER JOIN sma_service_activite
                       ON sma_service_activite.id_activite =
                          sma_notes_conso.id_activite
               INNER JOIN sma_service
                       ON sma_service.id_service
        WHERE  sma_service.id_entites IN( 20 )
               AND sma_famille.id_service IN( 988, 989, 990 )
               AND sma_service_activite.id_famille = sma_famille.id_famille
               AND sma_service_activite.id_service = sma_famille.id_service
               AND sma_service_activite.id_service = sma_service.id_service
               AND date_conso = '2013-04-03'
        GROUP  BY sma_famille.famille,
                  sma_agents.nom) AS FN
       INNER JOIN sma_famille
               ON sma_famille.id_service
       INNER JOIN sma_service
               ON sma_service.id_service
WHERE  sma_service.id_entites IN( 20 )
       AND sma_famille.id_service IN( 988, 989, 990 )
       AND sma_service.id_service = sma_famille.id_service
       AND FN.famille = sma_famille.famille
GROUP  BY FN.famille
```

The query works correctly if i have only one id_service like:
Here the first one:

```
    AND sma_famille.id_service IN(988)
```

and i get these resultset:

```
    |9  |Math|
    |13 |English|
    |2  |Bio|
```

Here the second one

```
    AND sma_famille.id_service IN(989)

    |5  |Math|
    |8  |English|
    |0  |Bio|
```

If i take both, he multiplied it with 2

```
    AND sma_famille.id_service IN(988,989)
```

and i get these resultset:

```
    |28 |Math|
    |42 |English|
    |4  |Bio|
```

But i don't want a multiplication, i want an addition of both 'id_service' like:

```
    |14  |Math|
    |21  |English|
    |2   |Bio|
```

and if i have three id's, than he multiplied it with 3!!!

Everytime if i add an 'id_service' he multiplied with number of id_service

I have 3 times the same Query for every Note. The Notes are 1, 2, 3. 
These example is only for the Note 2

Anybody can see the problem?

THX in advance

Comment: can you please post your table scripts and explain more exactly want you want to achieve eith your script? Without this info it might be hard to find the problem.

Comment: You can upload them to scribd and just post a link here...

Comment: OK, here you can find the table script:  http://www.workupload.com/file/Y9xX3Bl   THX

Comment: thanks. But to be honest I do not fully understand what you want to achieve with your script. Can you give some background info?

Comment: Here i have add datas to the tablescripts and the script with the query to execute   http://www.workupload.com/file/zTeQlc0   Hope that helps to understand. THX

Answer (score 0):

I think I found your problem:

You did not set the INNER JOIN correctly. Thus your query did a cartesian join and multiplicated the values. The follwing should be correct:

```
SELECT DISTINCT round( avg( AVG =1 ) * count( AVG ) ) AS New, sma_famille.famille
                            FROM (...
                            ) AS FN
                            INNER JOIN sma_famille ON sma_famille.id_service = FN.id_service -- added join criteria
                            INNER JOIN sma_service ON sma_service.id_service = FN.id_service -- added join criteria
                            WHERE sma_service.id_entites IN(20)
                            AND sma_famille.id_service IN(988,989,990) 
                            AND sma_service.id_service = sma_famille.id_service
                            AND FN.famille = sma_famille.famille
                            GROUP BY FN.famille;
```

Comment: Here i add datas to the tables and i add a sql script to execute the procedur. I hope it helps to understand.  http://www.workupload.com/file/zTeQlc0 THX
THX

Comment: Anybody an idea or solution? THX

Comment: i have changed my answer. I hope this helps :)

Comment: Hi, sorry that i answered so late. I have test your changes, but i get an mysql error: Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'FN.id_service' in 'on clause' How to get the 'FN' as known? THX